# How can I create a trigger to verify that a Varchar contains 3 Substrings

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle and I am trying to create a Trigger that tells me if a Varchar contains atleast one of the 3 substring that I need it to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use a trigger when you can just use a check constraint?

```
alter table t
    add constraint chk_table_col
        check (col like '%ABC%' or col like '%DEF%' or col like '%GHI%');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Abde - Gordon't question stands: WHY did you even think about triggers? Are you taking a class, and is this a homework assignment? If it is for actual (real-life) work, take some time to think about this. Constraints should almost always be enforced by adding check constraints, not triggers. And, when you ask a question here, ask the original question (How do I enforce the rule that ..... ) - not your idea of how to solve it (trigger). See http://xyproblem.info/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Is actually a project for college,and the data that they gave us is pretty useless they just give an example without explaining.Thanks  again for the advice.